# Error installing ath9k Wireless Driver for Ubuntu 12.10

Tags: drivers, compiling, install-from-source, make

I'm following the instructions of [this external link](http://linuxwireless.org/en/users/Drivers/ath9k#Get_the_latest_ath9k_driver).

When I enter `sudo make install }}}` I get the following error:

```
make -C /lib/modules/3.5.0-17-generic/build M=/home/jonathan/compat-wireless-3.6.8-1 modules
make: *** /lib/modules/3.5.0-17-generic/build: No such file or directory.  Stop.
make: *** [modules] Error 2
```

Comment: First: open the terminal. Second: go to the source folder, `cd path`. Third: unzip the source, `tar jxf compat-wireless-3.6.8-1.tar.bz2`. Four: build it, `make`. Five: install it, `sudo make install`. It works?

Comment: Sorry for the really late reply.  I'm trying it again right now.

Comment: Don't worry. But remember to tell use your results.

Answer (score 0):

You need some packages before you can build it.

Please refer to: https://gist.github.com/chrisjlee/3406323